# Unity. Подъем одного объекта с разных сторон

Tags: c#, unity3d

Допустим есть объект(куб) и допустим при нажатии на кнопку(допустим на клавиатуре E)(картинка 1)е поднималась всего лишь одна чать этого куба, а что бы его выровнять  нужно нажать на другую кнопку(допустим на клавиатуре Q)(картинка 2), вообще возможно такое

[image: куб][image: поднятая у куба вверх одна сторона][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью пустых объектов легко решается.

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        Cube.transform.RotateAround(LeftPoint.position, Vector3.forward, _speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        Cube.transform.RotateAround(RightPoint.position, Vector3.back, _speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

LeftPoint и RightPoint - поля типа Transform. Их нужно получить с пустых объектов, расположенных на левой и правой нижних гранях самого куба.

Vector3.forward и  Vector3.Back актуальны для перемещения по оси Y, если ось другая направления векторов надо поменять.

_speed - скорость перемещения.

Вот картинка для наглядности:
[image: Unity Cube]

Comment: Спасибо за более подробный ответ) помогли

Comment: @JohoTila чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Первый ответ бы основан на нефизическом взаимодействии.
Я же предложу физическую модель.

т.к. в юнити нельзя применять ускорение к точке обьекта (может и можно, но я про такие способа не знаю), то я предложу обходной путь:

Создать джоинты с обоих сторон "кирпича" которые прикрепить к другим обьектам. Или невидимым или к пустым если это возможно (не в курсе, никогда джоинтами не пользовался) и, собственно, придавать ускорение именно этим обьектам. А они в свою очередь будут тянуть ту или иную сторону кирпича в нужном направлении.

Comment: [Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker ответь отдельным ответом, я удалю свой

Comment: У меня нет времени на полноценный ответ, поэтому я и написал комментарий. Наличие этого API не инвалидирует твой ответ, так что не вижу смысла его удалять.